# Transform Node-Labeled Graph to equivalent Edge-Labeled

Tags: graph-theory

Given a Node-Labeled graph, i.e., a graph where only vertices have labels, I would like to create an equivalent Edge-Labeled graph, i.e., a graph where only edges have labels.

I know how to do the opposite.
In particular, given an edge-labeled  node-unlabeled graph, I can transform each labeled edge (with unlabeled source and destination)  to a pair of edges with a new node, where the original source and destination nodes have a default `NIL` label, the new node has label the original edge-label, and the edge `(s)-label-(d)` becomes the pair of edges `(s)--(label)` and `(label)--(d)`.

Comment: What does "equivalent" mean to you here?

Comment: Have you heard of the line graph: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_graph?

Comment: For equivalent I mean, for example, that  I can solve subgraph-isomorphism  on one and get the same answer on the corresponding transformed graph.

Comment: I was not aware of Line graphs. Taking a look right now, thanks!

Comment: Given that each vertex $v$ is labeled by a label $l(v)$ we can label each edge $(v,u)$ by a pair $(l(v), l(u))$.

Comment: This also makes sense intuitively, and does not blow up the size of the graph, but does this preserve subgraph-isomorphism? Again, my intuition is yes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the various comments, here is the possible solutions I've found:

### 1) Construct the corresponding [Line Graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_graph), informally meaning:

- For each edge (u,v)  create a new node n(u,v) (label for the node is the edge label
- For each *new node*, connect it to all other *new nodes* that have the same incident node in the original graph (in practice each node in the graph is transformed into a clique)

  (*by @bob-krueger*)

#### 1.1) Pros/Cons

- Number of Nodes in the new graphs = Number of Edges in the original
- A great number of cliques is created
- Number of labels stays the same
- Theoretically sound and well understood

### 2) Transfer Node labels directly onto Edges

- Given that each vertex `v` is labeled by a label `l(v)`
- label each edge `(v,u)` by a pair `(l(v),l(u))`
- (in practice one can concatenate strings)

  (*by @alex-ravsky*)

#### 2.1) Pros/Cons

- Graph structure is preserved (Nodes/Edges)
- Works with undirected graphs
- Number of labels is now $|L|^2$

### 2bis) Transfer Node labels directly onto Edges, preserve direction

** this is only for node labeled, edge directed graphs. **

- Same as above, but
- Given that each vertex `v` is labeled by a label `l(v)` , and
- Each edge is a tuple ${\langle}v,u{\rangle} \neq {\langle}u,v{\rangle}$
- label each edge  ${\langle}v,u{\rangle}$ by the single `l(v)`

#### 2.1) Pros/Cons

- Graph structure is preserved (Nodes/Edges)
- Works with undirected graphs
- Number of labels still the same $|L|$